# Scope of enumerators in C++

Tags: c++, memory, enums, scope

How the members of enums are accessed outside of enum since all members scope is limited to their block.

```
    #include<iostream>
    enum{MON,TUE,WED};

    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        cout << TUE;//How TUE is accessed since it has to be limited to enum's scope
        return 0;
}
```

1. How the scope of enum members are outside of enums block since as in classes or structures the scope of it's member is limited to the block they defined.
2. Since we are not creating object of enums then when the memory is allocated to enum members?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: That's not how an [unscoped enumeration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Unscoped_enumeration) works. It's how [**scoped** enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all members scope is limited to their block

*No*.

An `enum` in C++ has the same scope as the namespace it's defined in, which in your case is the global scope.

What you have is an [unscoped enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320603/are-unscoped-enumerations-still-useful). Maybe you are confused with [scoped enums](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations).

---

PS: [The usage of anonymous enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147008/the-usage-of-anonymous-enums).

Comment: Thanx, I had no idea of scoped enum.

Comment: @MohammadAdil you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Unscoped enums *leak* their names outside the `enum {}` braces in which they are defined and into the scope owning the enum which is a global scope, in your case. That's why you can't have a variable with the same name as one of the enums. Scoped enums don't leak their names outside the enum scope in which they are defined.

Comment: Nice answer Ron, I edited your answer, if you want tell me to rollback the edit.

Comment: @gsamaras Appreciate the edit. Right on the money.

Answer (score 2):

> all members scope is limited to their block

No, that's not the case for an `enum` in C++: the scope is the namspace in which the `enum` is defined. That's the *global* one in your case.

The `enum class` of C++11 onwards addresses this by localising the `enum` values to that `class`.